# Data Annotation model validation for Required attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my web api project, I have this code which uses Data Annotation Required attribute to validate. But when I test it using Postman, it can still go through.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> IsAccountClosed([Required] string nric)
    {
      // code removed for brevity
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting? So that request cannot be accepted without this `nric` parameter?

Comment: If nric is null or empty, I expect it to return the error without continue further. or I need to   (!ModelState.IsValid) to return it as bad request?

Comment: The `[Required]` attribute allows you to use `ModelState.IsValid` construct.  As model binding and model validation occur before the execution of a controller action or a Razor Pages handler method.it's the app's responsibility to inspect `ModelState.IsValid` and react appropriately. So you should use [`ModelState.IsValid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state) inside then it would act what you are expecting.

Comment: What do you want? clientside vlidate or serverside validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my web api project, I have this code which uses Data Annotation Required attribute to validate. But when I test it using Postman, it can still go through?

The `[Required]` attribute allows you to use `ModelState.IsValid` construct. As model binding and model validation occur before the execution of a controller action or a Razor Pages handler method.it's the app's responsibility to inspect `ModelState.IsValid` and react appropriately. So you should use `ModelState.IsValid` inside then it would act what you are expecting.

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IsAccountClosed([Required] string nric)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            return Ok();
           
        }
```

**Note:** It should also work even you don't use `ModelState.IsValid` attribute because `model validation` executes before the [`controller being executed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state).

**Output:**

[image]